# Query around Websphere addnode and registernode features

Tags: websphere

I just completed reading a book on WAS by stevens.

I wish to know the difference between "registernode.sh" and "addnode.sh".

I thought both are used to federate(group) nodes to a single cell.

registernode.sh has been introduced recently i believe.

So, how are they different ? Please give me a complete explanation even though it may be lengthy.

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are used in 2 different management models.

### registerNode

> Use the `registerNode` command to register a stand-alone node with an administrative agent so that the administrative agent can manage the node.

Administrative agent is used to manage many **stand-alone** instances running **on the same host**. It is used in so called `flexible management` administration. It is not creating single cell. You cannot create clusters in this mode, nor manage remote nodes. You would need additional JobManager profile to send jobs to multiple administrative agents.

### addNode

> The `addNode` command incorporates an application server installation into a cell.

Cell is defined by **deployment manager** profile and is used to build **distributed management** model where you may have **several different hosts**, where each has node agent added to the deployment manager. You administer your all nodes via deployment manager. In this model you can also create clusters, which may span horizontally and/or vertically. This model requires WebSphere Application Server Network deployment edition.

For more details see the following links and the redbook:

- [Administering nodes and resources](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tagt_admin.html?lang=en)
- [registerNode command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/ragt_registerNode.html?lang=en)
- [Administrative agent](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cagt_adminagent.html?lang=en)
- [addNode command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_addnode.html?lang=en)
- Check chapter 3 of the [WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Concepts, Planning, and Design Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248022.html?Open) Redbook

If after reading all these resources, you will still have doubts, feel free to add more specific questions.